# vue.js wrong transition group animation position

Tags: animation, vuejs2

at first I'm css beginner
I was trying to make vue.js animation for some items and it worked well but I got wrong animation

-We have button to add element to the array randomly

-We can click at element to remove it

problem:

-The animation always run on the last item

I expected that vue js should apply animation on the item which added or removed

What is the wrong in code that make the animation go wrong ??

What should i change or add to make the animation work correctly ??

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myNumbers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    highestNumberInMyNumbers: 4
  },
  methods: {
    addNumber() {
      this.highestNumberInMyNumbers++;
      this.myNumbers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.myNumbers.length), 0, this.highestNumberInMyNumbers);
    },
    removeNumber(element) {
      this.myNumbers.splice(element, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.mix-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mix-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  animation: mixing-in 600ms ease-in forwards;
}

.mix-leave {}

.mix-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1000ms;
  animation: mixing-out 0.4s ease-in forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes mixing-in {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-20px) translateY(20px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes mixing-out {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-20px) translateY(-20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <h2>group transition for directive v-for </h2>
  <hr>
  <button @click="addNumber">Add number</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <transition-group name="mix" mode="out-in">

        <li class="alert alert-success list-unstyled" style="height: 40px; padding: 10px 15px;margin-bottom: 8px;cursor: pointer;" v-for="(number,index) in myNumbers" @click="removeNumber(index)" :key="index">{{number}}
        </li>
      </transition-group>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**There is a bug in `transition-group`!**

**When you bind the  `key`  of `li` as the `index`, every time you remove a `li`, the animation always happend at the last `li` element.**

**So, if you want to use the animation with `li` , you can bind the `key` with `number` in your case.**

```
<transition-group name="mix"
                  mode="out-in">
    <li class="alert alert-success list-unstyled"
        style="height: 40px; padding: 10px 15px;margin-bottom: 8px;cursor: pointer;"
        v-for="(number,index) in myNumbers"
        @click="removeNumber(index)"
        :key="index">
        {{number}}
    </li>
</transition-group>
```

vs

```
<transition-group name="mix"
                  mode="out-in">
    <li class="alert alert-success list-unstyled"
        style="height: 40px; padding: 10px 15px;margin-bottom: 8px;cursor: pointer;"
        v-for="(number,index) in myNumbers"
        @click="removeNumber(index)"
        :key="number">
        {{number}}
    </li>
</transition-group>
```

**Finally, if you use animation with `transition-group` , do not bind the `key` to `index` , instead of `item` or `number` (in your case).**

**No matter what , make sure the `key` has the unique value.**

Comment: In this case the array over which you for-loop contains unique numbers. But if it contains duplicate numbers this will not work. If the array contains objects it will work but you will get a vuejs error as well.

Comment: But then how do we deal with this when we have same items in the list? @user1081577 have you found solution for duplicates?

Answer (score 14):

## Solution

Don't use **index** anywhere in the **v-bind:key** when using transition or transition-group.

## Explanation

There is a bug/missing documentation, as well as bad documentation in the cookbook on vuejs.org, but there's a detailed explanation in the comments [1] on how indexes work, but no recognition this is a problem for developers in it's current state.

I have posted a few times to github, but the Vue.js developers there seem dismissive at best and refuse to either document this behavior or recognize this as a problem.

## Reproduction of bug/error

There are three examples in the codepen below. The #1 works, the #2 uses :key="index" (your specific error above) and #3 uses :key="item +'_'+ index".

#2 and #3 give the error you are experiencing.

https://codepen.io/megacromulent/pen/wEzWNL

Summary of codepen:

This one **works**: (using item as :key)

```html
<transition-group name="fade" tag="ol">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items"
      v-bind:key="item">
    {{item}}
  </li>
</transition-group>
```

This one **fails**: (using index as :key)

```html
<transition-group name="fade" tag="ol">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items"
      v-bind:key="index" >
    {{item}}
  </li>
</transition-group>
```

This one **fails worse**: (concatenating index with string in :key)

```html
<transition-group name="fade" tag="ol">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in items"
      v-bind:key="item + '_' + index" >
    {{item}}
  </li>
</transition-group>
```

## Bug report (rejected)

I submitted this bug report to Vue.js devs here:

**"Transition-group animates only last element if using index as the key"**

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8718

It got closed instantly, so based on their input (requested I do a PR for comment, but that is not in my wheelhouse) I followed up with this feature request for the dev build to give an error, which would solve the problem at it's root.

## Feature request (follow up, also rejected)

**"Dev build console error when using index in :key value with v-for and transitions"**

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8730

It seems reasonable to put a dev error on this issue, but the vue.js developers seem to think we should be able to figure this out on our own. I hope they come around and see this as a real issue. It's cost me hours of testing and reporting time to figure out.

I hope this helps other devs wasting time with this issue.

**References**

[1] https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8718#issuecomment-416909724

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this case:
create a random generated string for your array, then use this randomly generated string as the key.

template

```
<div v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="row.randomKey">
   ...
</div>
```

script

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        add() {
            this.rows.push({
                id: null,
                name: '',
                randomKey: this.generateRandomKey()
            })
        },
        remove(index) {
            this.currency_exchange.splice(index, 1)
        },
        generateRandomKey() {
            let length = 10
            return Math.round((Math.pow(36, length + 1) - Math.random() * Math.pow(36, length))).toString(36).slice(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Megacromulent

Good research!

**For those who, like me, came here looking for:**

It is likely that the animation occurs when the key is changed i.e. When deleting and creating an element, if the key does not change, then there will be no animation.
When the array changes, all the elements are rebuilt, which means the keys are also rewritten, and if they change on the element, this will make the element go away and appear.

Megacromulent let's see:

In the second case, the option with index - we remove the first element of the array, new keys are placed over all the remaining elements in the component - but in the beginning they will be the same 0,1,2 ... i.e. The keys of the first list will not change and therefore the elements will not be destroyed and therefore will not be animated.

In the third version, the key for all elements will change every time, i.e. All elements will be redrawn i.e. Removed and rebuilt, animation will work for all elements

Well, in the first version. If the items are the same, it will be the same as with the index because the key will not change, which means, in the case of all the same, only the last one will be animated, i.e. When adding and removing items to the end of the list.